# How to start a file such as a batch file after a certain amount of loops?

Tags: vbscript

This is my script

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
wscript.sleep 1800000
do
    if colCDROMs.Count >=1 then
        For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
            colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
        Next
        For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
            colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
        Next
    End if
    wscript.sleep 600000
loop
```

I am going to make it eject the cd tray after 30 minutes of starting up and every ten minutes after, what I want to know is how to open up a certain text file after say about 3 loops?

Comment: If counter> 3 open file?

Comment: Do you mean open a text file in the script (use [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx)) or to the screen (say notepad)?

Comment: Ok lets say the cd ejects 3 times, i want it to open up a certain batch file. I'm pretty noob at this so idk where it would go or how to do it. I understand i need to know the file destination and how to find that out but what line of text would i use to open the file and where would i put it?

Comment: like i said i am a complete noob at this. can i put it anywhere as long as it is before the loop?

Comment: It will open the drawer then close it again, but I think it would be so fast you wouldn't notice

Answer (score 0):

for what its worth... This will open the text file `file` every time after the 3rd time the CD drawer opens. you could set count back to zero if you wanted...

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
wscript.sleep 1800000
count = 0
do
    if colCDROMs.Count >=1 then
        count = count + 1
        For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
            colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
        Next
        For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
            colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
        Next
    End if
    If count >= 3 Then
      file = "c:\path\to\my\file.txt"
      CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe """ & file & """"
    end if
    wscript.sleep 600000
loop
```